# Uploading to imgur/minus using the Share menu in Preview

Tags: macos, upload, imgur

Is there a way to add Imgur or min.us to ths "Share" menu in Preview?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only software I know is **[ImageShareUr](https://www.simplicate.info/imageshareur/)** for Imgur, but apparently it doesn't work anymore on Sierra. But if you are still on El Capitan or earlier, it's a great app to have, because the Share menu is accessible almost everywhere in the system; you can even upload pictures embedded in webpages directly to Imgur.

It seems that the developer is dealing with health issues, and there might not be an update for Sierra and later, so I assume we should keep this topic open.

Comment: I'm alright with leaving the topic open. I asked this question so long ago I no longer have a working Mac :-)

Comment: Their website is now offline. It seems that **ImageShareUr** will not be developed further.

Answer (score 0):

Found another software called **[imGuru](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imguru/id1012308785?mt=12)** which is for free on the AppStore. However, the app fails to copy the image URL to the clipboard on my system, and it doesn't support anonymous upload like **ImageShareUr** does (did).

Another app is **[iPic](https://en.toolinbox.net/iPic/)**, also for free on the MAS, but you need to buy the Pro license (in-app purchase) to get imgur support. Downsides: doesn't support anonymous upload either, and it's not available via the "Share" menu.

Still looking for a good replacement for **ImageShareUr** with free imgur support, anonymous uploading, and "Share" menu integration.

Comment: Do either of the apps you recommend add Imgur to the Share menu in Preview?

Comment: Of course, imGuru does, otherwise I wouldn't have posted in this topic. Still gets downvoted by some idiot. Ah well. At any rate, imGuru doesn't work on my system, but maybe others have more luck. iPic is missing the Share menu feature, so that's just some bonus info. It's close, though, because it integrates with the Services menu.